# Navigate Buttons in flash builder

Tags: flash

How to make a button to link to another page when using adobe flash builder to make an ios app

Answer (score 0):

here you have an example in my main view i have 1 buton, when i click it send me to Autoview(this is the name where i want to go)
'

```
        protected function manualview_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            navigator.pushView(views.Autoview);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
  <s:Button id="butAuto" left="272" top="9" width="187" height="73" label="Automatic"
          click="manualview_clickHandler(event)" enabled="true" horizontalCenter="5"
          verticalCenter="-108"/>
 '
```

Comment: I am creating a stat book. What I have is a roster and next to all the players names I have a view button. What I want it to do is when you click the button pull up a persons stats. I have another .mxml file called Player1 for the first person view file. I want to be able to click that button and navigate to that Player1.mxml file. Is their any way I can do this?